# How scope works in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why this works?

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
    $scope.From = "Santa";
    $scope.To = "Claus";
});
```

and why this one doesn't?

```
app.controller("ctrl", function(scope){
    scope.From = "Santa";
    scope.To = "Claus";
});
```

this too doesn't work...

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($x){
    $x.From = "Santa";
    $x.To = "Claus";
});
```

As far as I know, `$scope` is only a parameter and private to the function. How is it possible that changing the name will make it not work?

PS. I'm just starting to learn AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has three different ways to perform dependency injection.

### Method 1: Injection array

This is the most informative syntax, in my opinion, because it gives the developer more of a clear picture of what's going on.

```
controllerName.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
function controllerName($scope, $http) {
   // code here
}
```

As you can see, all dependency injection is, at it's core, is an additional property that tells angular what stuff needs to exist before the function can run. Angular ensures these services have been instantiated and then feeds them to the function as arguments. The names that angular matches against are the strings provided in the injection array. In this syntax, the actual function arguments can be named ANYTHING (javascript legal) and they will map to the service in the corresponding position of the injection array. `$scope` could be named `$x` in the argument list and it would still work fine, as long as the injection array has the proper name.

## Method 2: Injectable function

Angular also has a particular syntax for declaring functions which are "injectable". The angular documentation lists which functions are injectable, but, to name a few examples, controllers, services, directives, and component template functions are injectable. The syntax looks like this:

```
['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { // code here }]
```

As you can see, this is similar to the first syntax, except that it combines the injection list with the function definition. The first n - 1 arguments are strings that angular will use to find required dependencies to inject, the nth argument is the function which you want to inject those dependencies into. Again, the name of the arguments to the function means NOTHING. They map to the corresponding service in the first `n-1` strings of the array. This method is reliable, and clearer to the developer, but, in my opinion it starts to look messy as the dependency list grows. And I don't like the fact that it tends to obscure the actual function definition. This is just a matter of preference.

## Method 3: Interpreted Dependency Names

In the event that you've done neither of the above, angular will do it's best to guess what service you want to use by assuming that you named the provided argument identically to the name of the service/dependency you wish to inject. So, it just looks like this (the same syntax you put in your post):

```
function($scope, $http) { //code here }
```

With this method angular uses the actual name of the argument to interpret what dependency to inject. This method seems nice, simple and clean, but, in short, you should NEVER use this method. The most important reason is that it's not minification safe. A good minifier will also "mangle" your code, turning the above code into `function(a,b) { // code }` which angular will have no way of understanding. Whereas minifiers will not touch string literals. Additionally, if someone, like you, is confused about the fact that the name of the variable actually matters, it can easily introduce bugs.

If you would like the cleanliness of the third method with the reliablity of the first two, I would recommend you look at the post processing tool NgAnnotate: https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate. I use this in all my projects, and it's a lifesaver.

Comment: Wow! Very well explained. The tip about minification is very helpful, I could have decided to go with the 3rd method without realizing the risk.

Comment: It's k, as long as it helped you out, I'll survive the downvote ;)

Although, of course, if the person who downvoted did so due to inaccurate information, please fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

Please Refer this: [DOCS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

[DOCS2](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/806530/dependency-injection-in-controller-of-angularjs)

> The $ prefix denotes a variable, parameter, property, or method that
>   belongs to the core of Angular.

All of the below will work fine:

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
    $scope.From = "Santa";
    $scope.To = "Claus";
});

app.controller("ctrl",['$scope', function(scope){
    scope.From = "Santa";
    scope.To = "Claus";
}]);

app.controller("ctrl",['$scope', function($x){
    $x.From = "Santa";
    $x.To = "Claus";
}]);
```

1. Implicit Annotation - your first example code
2. Inline Array Annotation - your second example code

Comment: I'm curious why mine won't work. Does angular checks the function if the parameter is named `$scope` then when the function is called by angular, it will pass the desired object? "scope" in this case?

Comment: I'm not asking for a workaround or a solution, I want to know what's under the hood. I hope I'm making myself clear.

Comment: Okay... I read it. Please tell me if I understand it correctly, since there is no type info of the parameters in the function, DI will not know what to pass if the parameter names are random, then Angular decided to use $ symbol to identify dependencies.

Comment: Yes. And you also need to understand two ways of DI, Implicit Annotation, Inline Array Annotation

Comment: That must be it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It works as the $scope is a own nice thing for angular. many of the predefined factories, serivces ect uses the $ sign. for examples, you allso have $rootscope, $http ect :)